# Select SUM() throws "Column not found" exception [42122-193] in H2

Tags: jdbc, h2

The execution of the following statement:

```
SELECT SUM(p.price)
FROM Product p
```

via JDBC on an embedded H2 database throws exception:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "price" not found
>   [42122-193]

How can I make it work?

Comment: Please post the code used to execute and the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it doesn't matter. The problem is in the SQL statement, not in the client code. Also, the full stacktrace depends on your client code, so it is not important. The import thing is using h2.jdbc driver. Similar problem is mentioned here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/MJbvu2-7aaQ

Comment: That might be apparent to you, but not to me. It is more valuable to have the context of the code, and the exception stacktrace to actually show where the error occurs. Because my initial guess would not be that the problem is not the query, but an attempt to use of `ResultSet.getXxx("price")`, which of course doesn't work because that is not the label of the column in the result set. Your answer seems to assume that the problem is purely fixed by adding an alias, which I am not willing to accept at face value.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, you are right! That was the problem. I was too stupid to look at it closely. If the column name passed to ResultSet's method is named "sum(p.price)" than it is working as excepted without exception. I will rewrite the question and I will happily accept your answer as best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an alias for the column used in SUM():

```
SELECT SUM(p.price) as price
FROM Product p
```

**Beware!** The alias has to be named exactly as the column.